# WCF Rest - Allowing both SSL/TLS and non-secure connections to the same hostname

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, ssl

I have a RESTful WCF service hosted in IIS. It has its own custom WebServiceHostFactory and WebServiceHost subclass.

Right now its IIS website is configured with both TLS and non-TLS bindings (both to the same IP address). However when a request comes in on the unsecure IIS binding this error occurs (buried in an SGML comment in an ASP.NET YSoD):

```
[EndpointNotFoundException]: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://mywebservice.com./MyService.svc/'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
[HttpException]: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://mywebservice.com./MyService.svc/'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

However I have no idea where I set these bindings up - because there is nowhere in my code or web.config file that told it to use "https://mywebservice.com/MyService.svc" in the first place.

I note that the exception details state the hostname as the root-absolute FQDN of "mywebservice.com." rather than the typical root-relative FQDN of "mywebservice.com" - is this of any significance?

EDIT (in response to comment): The IIS website has two bindings, one HTTP on port 80 and bound to one IP address, and another binding for HTTPS on port 443 on the same IP address. There are no host-header settings for either binding.

Comment: Do you have both https and http bindings configured in IIS MAnager | [Web Site] | Edit bindings... ?

Comment: Do you have both `httpGetEnabled="True"` and `httpsGetEnabled="True"` set in your `serviceMetadata`?  Can you post your server-side config?